# Difference of a normal(Dual array) microphone and a Digital Microphone

Tags: microphone

*backstory: So I have been searching for some laptops, and stumbled upon this question.*

The laptop A has an Dual Array Microphone, nothing special; the laptop B has an  Digital Microphone - *Digital and audio are not rhyming at least for me.*

As of the laptop's price an specs and the model-history, I can say A is luxury, delicate and B is old school, functional.

So what is the deference of a normal(Dual array) microphone and a Digital Microphone.
I did a google search and found [this](https://www.askmefast.com/What_is_difference_between_digital_microphone_and_digiral_dual_array_microphone-qna5856537.html) but the link is kinda off topic but the text of the search result is:

> Digital microphone appear in low-grade and high-death applications,
> including toys, computers, telephony , and sound studios. while, An
> array microphone uses ...

But I am more puzzled after that result.

After it, I got to know that Digital microphone is an mic with the all ICs inside.(what's that?)

Lastly my question is:
Difference of a normal(Dual array) microphone and a Digital Microphone as in

- quality
- lifetime

---

Edit 2021/9/8: Someone might be wondering why I would compare these *supposedly small* changes of laptops; It's because that laptop B has a low processor and cheap specs but comes with a media editing software bundle While A is *normal* as in the other listings - I had a suspicion that the company was whether selling a low Laptop with more software - to check it I checked the microphones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array mics (dual or otherwise) are like smaller versions of multi-mic setups. Using the differences in the two (or more) audio signals, a digital signal processor (DSP) can automatically figure out the difference between the main signal and any background noise. Laptops tend to use these for noise-cancelling during video conferencing calls.

A digital mic is simply a regular mic with a built-in analogue to digital converter (ADC). This means that the output signal is digital removing the need for a separate ADC. These tend to make use of gates, compressors and limiters to handle background noise removal.

When it comes to quality, I can't comment. It's a little like asking for a difference in quality between a truck or a car. You can't compare quality without more information. In the case of a microphone, you'd want to know things like frequency response curves or SPL (volume) tolerances.

The same goes for the lifetime. If you had two of the same cars and you used one for driving sensibly on smooth roads, but you used the other for rally driving, you'd expect a difference in their lifetimes. Using or storing microphones in noisy environments or adverse conditions will shorten their lives.

As a regular user, I don't think you'll notice much difference in microphones from laptop to laptop. If you're planning on using the built-in mics to attempt making high-quality recordings, then I would strongly suggest you invest in a better external mic and ADC instead.

Comment: So the ADC is in the digital mic while not in the array mic.

Comment: _attempt making high-quality recordings_: Hardly I would make a song or something.

Comment: I can't comment on your specific Array Mic. I would expect that some have their own dedicated ADC, and some don't.